# :first-child and other selectors do not seem to work

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, attributes, css-selectors

let's say this HTML

```
<ul class="slider">
    <li><img id="img1" src="img/slide-1.jpg"/></li>
    <li><img src="img/slide-2.jpg"/></li>
    <li><img src="img/slide-3.jpg"/></li>
</ul>
```

and in my jquery, i have

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var max_count = $(".slider").children().length;
    for(var rn=1;rn<=max_count;rn++)
        {
        var eg = $(".slider li:first-child").attr('id');
        $("#output").append(eg);
        }
});
```

when i put `#img1` instead of `.slider li:first-child`, it works fine, so im doing something wrong with the selector

Comment: what is the desired output

Comment: if you want the id of only one element then why use a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`li:first-child` selects `<li>` elements which are the first child of their parent.

You could do this:

```
$(".slider li:first-child img").attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without using the for loop like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".slider li").each(function(){
         $("#output").append($(this).children("img:first-child").attr("id"));
    });
});
```

Here is a working fiddle:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/xzMmD/
```